# Suitable reference on smooth manifolds for qualifying exam study?

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds

Is there a *single* suitable reference to study for the smooth manifold (geometry) half of a typical Topology/Geometry PhD preliminary exam at an average AMS group I school?  (Note: I know details about the presentation of these prelim tests varies, but at many schools there is a single Topology/Geometry exam, half of which is roughly smooth manifolds "Geometry" and the other half algebraic topology "Topology")

Being a bibliophile, I've invested some time looking around at various qualifying exam syllabi until something stuck out:  for Topology, relatively fewer books are listed.  It seems quite often a book like Algebraic Topology by Hatcher is listed along with one or two others (seemingly to cover certain small gaps).  Also, for Algebra, a few books often suffice... the books by Lang, Jacobson, and Dummit & Foote are often listed.  One or two of these together with an outlier often suffice.

Compare that to the situation with smooth manifolds.  One site (which I lost track of... UCR?) I saw listed as many as 8 books as references for the topic!  Many universities seem to use Guillemin & Pollack despite teaching manifolds abstractly, rather than as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This is understandable, but somewhat pedagogically suspect and in my own experience as a student, confusing.

It appears that the topic of smooth manifolds needs an expository text that fills the same role for Geometry as does Algebraic Topology (Hatcher) does for Topology.

Some sensible criteria:

- The book should treat manifolds abstractly
- The book should cover the foundation material in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, perhaps at a brisker pace
- The book should at least cover the material found in Guillemin & Pollack, suitably modified in light of the first condition above.

Does such a book exist?  Perhaps a second volume such as "Topics in Smooth Manifolds" by John M. Lee would do.

Alternatives to consider:

- Smooth Manifolds by Rajnikant Sinha
- An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu

Both seem fine, but like Lee's book, they don't quite cover all the topics you'd want to have covered.  Getting past all the foundation work seems to be quite a lot of work indeed.

Comment: No, such a book does not exist as far as I know.  I don't think anyone would want to read such a book.  The topics sound nice when you list them but when you lay it all out in a book form it would read like a 5-month long meal of barley and vegemite, with the occasional drink of water.  It might be nutritious, but most people would tire of it quite rapidly.  After reading Guillin and Pollack I came to the realization that abstract manifolds are a rarely-useful burden that simply delays the learning process for most students.

Comment: My main interest in asking this question is as a student... I would hope in studying for an preliminary exam I would have to study from at most 2 tomes... one for each subtopic.  If you are right then treating smooth manifolds in one semester as indicated by a typical qualifying exam syllabus may be impossible without certain shortcuts.

Comment: IMO it's a good thing there's no standard textbook, as it's good preparation for reality in the field.  One has to be adaptable.  But at any given university you can usually get a sense for the preferred perspectives of the people writing the exams.  Usually it follows closely to the perspective in recent courses on the subject.

Comment: You should consider reading Bott & Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology": not as a resource for smooth manifolds, nor as a resource for algebraic topology, but for the beautiful interplay between them. I benefited greatly from reading it in graduate school, not least because it broadened my perspective on what techniques might be applied to what problems.

Comment: It appears the new edition of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds book is much closer to the goal I stated.  In fact, if one counts the exercises it may cover everything I mentioned.  Certainly a few short notes in addition to that book would do the trick.